# ruby regex need to match only if a URL is found in a string once

Tags: ruby, regex

I'm trying to add conditional logic to determine if there's ***one*** regex match for a URL in a string.  Here's an example of the string:

```
string_to_match = "http://www.twitpic.com/23456 ran to catch the bus, http://www.twitpic.com/3456 dodged a bullet at work."
```

I only want to match if I determine there's one URL in the string, so the above string **wouldn't** be a match in the case I'm trying to solve.  I thought something like this would work:

```
if string_to_match =~  /[http\:\/\/]?/
   puts "you're matching more then once. bad man!"
end
```

But it doesn't!  How do I determine that there's only one match in a string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [String#scan](http://apidock.com/ruby/String/scan), you can use it this way:

```
if string_to_match.scan(/[http\:\/\/]/).count > 1
   puts "you're matching more then once. bad man!"
end
```

Comment: Thanks Mladen!  This is what worked for me: string_to_match.scan(/(http\:\/\/)/).length == 1.  You need to group with () otherwise each individual character that matches is inserted into the array.

Comment: You're right, sorry, I haven't tested the regex, just pasted the one from your question.

Answer (score 2):

The answer from Mladen is fine (counting the return from `scan`), but regular expressions already include the idea of matching the same thing multiple times or a particular number of times. In your case, you want to print the warning if your text occurs 2 or more times:

```
/(http:\/\/.+?){2,}/
```

Use `.+` or `.*`, depending on whether you want to require the URL to have some content or not. As it stands, the `.+?` will match 1 or more characters in a non-greedy fashion, which is what you want. A greedy quantifier would gobble up the entire string on the first try and then have to do a bunch of backtracking before ultimately finding multiple URLs.

Answer (score 1):

you could do it like this:

```
if string_to_match =~ /((http:\/\/.*?)http:\/\/)+/
```

this would match only if you have 2 (or more) occurrences of http://

Comment: ennuikiller, I'm looking to write conditional logic for a single  match of 'http://' in a string, not more then one match.  I think my phrasing might have been confusing.  Thanks for responding all the same!

Comment: to reverse the sense of the match simply replace =~ with !=